# is inclined bed therapy real?

Tags: sleep

I have discovered "Inclined Bed Therapy"

[They claim is very beneficial](https://inclinedbedtherapy.com/research)

Is this real therapy?

Why are all beds flat (conspiracy)?

Here some claims for the IBT

> sleep psychologist, entrepreneur and author Dr. Günther W.
> Amann-Jennson noted that both wild animals and domestic livestock like
> to sleep on the ground with their heads slightly uphill. This
> observation led him to study the effects of gravity on sleep.
>
> According to Gunther, inclined sleeping not only helps migraines, it
> can lower blood pressure, reduce water retention, improve varicose
> veins, and may even have the ability to help prevent Alzheimer’s, as
> some researchers believe the disease is due in part to excessive
> pressure in the head. It’s an intriguing theory, and an area of
> research that deserves more study.
>
> People who try inclined sleep report:
>
> Deeper sleep Fewer headaches and migraines Improvements in memory
> Better cognition Faster mental turnover

Comment: Grazing animals spend most of their waking hours with their head lower than their body.

Comment: @weathervane Counterpoint: Giraffes.

Comment: I'm not seeing a conspiracy here - It's just that flat beds are easier and more convenient to build and transport and we've always had (mostly) horizontal beds; I'm not nearly enough of a medical biologist to make any judgement on this guy's research, but it's entirely possible he's on to something that's worth looking into further -- but that's well outside this site's remit.

Comment: There is some evidence that raising the head of the bed may help relieve symptoms of acid reflux, e.g. https://bmcfampract.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12875-021-01369-0.  Obviously that's a much narrower benefit than the claim.

Comment: @Shadur true, but a giraffe is a browser, not a grazer. It's not for their health though.

Comment: I would be happy about seeing research but when I went to a sleep standard sleep doctor, he did recommend bed inclination to me. The first times I slept that way it lead to a lot of unexpected relaxation (I didn't expect much, but it was something cheap that my doctor recommended). My felt effect sizes decreased over time (it would be therefore interesting to see studies that check it over longer timeframes).

Comment: Inclined == using a pillow. I personally hate that and prefer sleeping on a perfectly flat hard bed. But have slept on all kinds of surfaces while hiking; the worst it head down a slope.